# Importing Date Attributes in DD/MM/YYYY format

Tags: magento2, import, programmatically, date

When importing products with date fields in format ***dd/mm/YYYY*** it throws this error:

> ***Value for 'special_to_date' attribute contains incorrect value in
>   row(s): 1, 2, 3***

From reading around I see that the date attribute needs to be imported in the following format:

***YYYY-mm-dd***

however changing the date format in the csv file before importing isn't really an option as Excel doesn't make this easy.

Is there a way to stop this error by programatically modifying the date format before the products are imported?

I assume I need to change something in

```
 /vendor/magento/module-import-export/Model/Import/
```

?

Comment: I am 100% sure that changing the time format in Excel is way more easier than you create a module for this reason.
Check this

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/06/23/excel-time-format-now-time-functions/

Comment: Open the csv with Notepad and use Find/Replace to put the dates in YYYY/MM/DD format.